# Error in helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet (line 10)

Tags: image-processing

Hi i working on **HOG**.

this is my code:

```
   % Get labels for each image. 
trainingLabels = trainingSet.Labels;
 % fitcecoc uses SVM learners and a 'One-vs-One' encoding scheme. 
classifier = fitcecoc(trainingFeatures, trainingLabels); 
% Extract HOG features from the test set. 
The procedure is similar to what % was shown earlier and is encapsulated as a helper function for brevity. 
[testFeatures, testLabels] = helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet(testSet, hogFeatureSize, cellSize);
 % Make class predictions using the test features.
 predictedLabels = predict(classifier, testFeatures);
```

The **error** occur on  `helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet` function please give me solution. Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: % Get labels for each image.
trainingLabels = trainingSet.Labels;
% fitcecoc uses SVM learners and a 'One-vs-One' encoding scheme.
classifier = fitcecoc(trainingFeatures, trainingLabels);
% Extract HOG features from the test set. The procedure is similar to what
% was shown earlier and is encapsulated as a helper function for brevity.
[testFeatures, testLabels] = helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet(testSet, hogFeatureSize, cellSize);

% Make class predictions using the test features.
predictedLabels = predict(classifier, testFeatures);

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this question more than a year ago, but I hope my answer will help future users.
If you get this error, "'Undefined function or variable 'helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet'", it's because this function is undefined! The code for function helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet is below:

```
 function [features, setLabels] = helperExtractHOGFeaturesFromImageSet(imds, 
    hogFeatureSize, cellSize)
% Extract HOG features from an imageDatastore.

setLabels = imds.Labels;
numImages = numel(imds.Files);
features  = zeros(numImages, hogFeatureSize, 'single');

% Process each image and extract features
for j = 1:numImages
    img = readimage(imds, j);
    img = rgb2gray(img);

    % Apply pre-processing steps
    img = imbinarize(img);

    features(j, :) = extractHOGFeatures(img,'CellSize',cellSize);
end
```